# How Can I Show Console Tab in Different Monitor for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

i'am using Eclipse and two monitors. My Laptos's screen is not enough big to show Console tap. Is there a way for showing Console Tab at different monitor screen?

Idea?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. You can drag the Console tap out of Eclipse workbench window. Then the view is detached from the workbench window. After the view is detached, you can move it to the other monitor screen.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else had the popped out console window move back to the primary monitor after it has been dragged to the secondary monitor?  Seems to happen when eclipse pops up a dialog box for some reason.

This is a bit annoying.  I like having a console window on a monitor I've got in portrait mode, very handy for watching unit tests execute.